# why will this only allow one type not both? php

Tags: php

I have created a page where modorators (group 2) can have their own page to show whats going on, banned users etc. I want admin (group 1) to be able to access the page as well. The function im using is:

```
function mod_protect() {
    global $user_data;
    if (has_access($user_data['user_id'], 1, 2) === false) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
    }
```

when i use just the mods group number (2) it works fine but when i try to put both in only 1 works??

Sorry has_access code:

```
function has_access($user_id, $type) {
    $user_id    = (int)$user_id;
    $type       = (int)$type;

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND `type` = $type"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: What is `has_access()`?

Comment: show the code for `has_access()`

Comment: `has_access()` only uses 2 parameters, not 3.

Comment: You're only picking up the first two parameters to has_access(). In your example, 2 is being ignored. You want to either specifically write has_access() for 2 _or more_ values, or make the second one an array.

Comment: The best advice a person could give you is to learn some basics before trying to tackle whatever it is you're tackling. To be frank (with the goal of being helpful), if you don't understand something as basic as how function parameters and arguments work, then you need to cover some fundamentals before building something that interacts with a database.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw everyones allowed at least 1 dumb comment no? lol

Comment: If you're referring to mine, har har, but you're still in the same boat. If you're referring to yours, it doesn't appear to be a dumb comment so much as a lack of basic understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest this as an alternative approach to your `has_access()` function:

```
function has_access($user_id, $type) {
  $user_id    = (int)$user_id;
  if( is_array( $type ) {
    $types = implode(',',$type);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` =      $user_id AND `type` IN ($types)"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
  else {
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` =      $user_id AND `type` = $type"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Doing this way allows you to either pass a single type to the `has_access()` function or pass an array of types to the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you could do this (though it would use two queries when one could easily be used - that is optimization for you to do though):

```
if (has_access($user_data['user_id'], 1) === false && has_access($user_data['user_id'], 2) === false) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```